# ndb models, decorators, nested functions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, decorator, app-engine-ndb

I'm looking for some help with my app. Here's sample code first (stripped down from about 2k lines...) and I'll try to explain what I'm looking for later:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import webapp2
import json

class User(ndb.Model):
  company_              = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

  @property
  def company(self):
    return {} if not self.company_ else self.company_

  @company.setter
  def company(self, value):
    if value:
      self.company_ = self.company_.expand(value) if self.company_ else [value]
    else:
      self.company_ = []
    self.put()

class Company(ndb.Model):
  administrator         = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, repeated=True)
  manager               = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, repeated=True)

  # FAKE decorator
  @staticmethod
  def administrator(handler):
    def check_requirements(self, *a, **kw):
      if True:
        return
      else:
        return handler(self, *a, **kw)
    return check_requirements

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def jwrite(self, **kw):
    return self.response.out.write( json.dumps(kw) )

class require(BaseHandler):
  @staticmethod
  def login(handler):
    def check_requirements(self, *a, **kw):
      if not self.auth.get_user_by_session():
        self.redirect('/', abort=True)
      else:
        return handler(self, *a, **kw)
    return check_requirements

class ApiHandler(BaseHandler):
  @require.login
  def post(self, model, action, key=''):
    method = '_post_%s' % model
    try:
      getattr(self, method)(action, key)
    except Exception as error:
      return self.jwrite( error = error)

  def _post_company(self, action, key):

    if action == 'create':
      data = dict(self.request.POST)
      """ Company.create( data ) method:
          Populates Company instance with POST data.
          Assigns first user that created the company
            both administrator and manager roles.
      """
      key_ = Company.create( data ) 
      if key_:
        self.user.company = key_
      return

    elif action == 'delete':

      @Company.administrator
      def delete_all_user_companies(self):
        ndb.delete_multi( self.user.company )
        self.user.company = None
        return

      companies = ndb.get_multi( self.user.company )
      if self.user.key in map( lambda c: c.administrator, companies):
        delete_all_user_companies(self)

    elif action == 'update':

      @Company.manager
      def update_company(self, key):
        data = dict(self.request.POST)
        """ Company.update( key, data ) method:
            Populates Company instance with POST data
        """
        key_ = Company.update( key, data )
        if key_:
          return

      company = ndb.Key(Company, key).get()
      if self.user.key in company.manager.extend(company.administrator):
        update_company(self)
```

As you can see, I have User and Company models. User can have multiple companies and companies can have multiple users, which can be administrators or managers. You'll notice some decorators and nested functions - most of them are fake (; But that's what I'm looking for...

I'm doing basic login check with **@require.login** decorator (I've put it in separate class, just because it looks cleaner in code - @require.login vs @BaseHandler.require_login). With it I've "secured" post method of my API, and now I need to do additional check for roles - administrators can do some things managers cant. I will need to do this check in several other places, so I think it would be a good place for decorator functions, but I can't figure out how to write them. My first questions is:

1. What would be good place for this decorator? Should I put it in Company class or somewhere in the ApiHandler class? My first instinct is to put it in Company class, but I'm not sure how to deal with scope - I'll need to get user instance (self.user.company list) in there somehow...
2. Next thing is **manager** decorator. How do I write this as decorator:

   ```
     company = ndb.Key(Company, key).get()
     if self.user.key in company.manager.extend(company.administrator):
       update_company(self)
   ```

   and use it as **@Company.manager** or **@requre.manager**, depending on the answer to my first question?
3. Another decorator for **administrator** that's bit more complex - I have to check if user is administrator for all his companies, and delete ones where he is while keeping ones where he isn't:

   ```
     companies = ndb.get_multi( self.user.company )
     if self.user.key in map( lambda c: c.administrator, companies ):
       delete_all_user_companies(self)
   ```

   I'm not even sure if this map() function is correct and if the code would work, didn't try it yet - it's just a pseudo-code placeholder for now...
4. Last question: Should I be concerned about POST request hacking? Based on the sample code above, is it possible that some user can make custom POST requests and delete or update company that's not his?

Any help, comments or insights would be appreciated (; Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've solved this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import webapp2
import json

class User(ndb.Model):
  company_              = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

  @property
  def company(self):
    return {} if not self.company_ else self.company_

  @company.setter
  def company(self, value):
    if value:
      # self.company_ = self.company_.expand(value) if self.company_ else [value]
      # Lists mutate when expanded. Code above was returning None
      self.company_ = self.company_ + [value] if self.company_ else [value]
    else:
      self.company_ = []
    self.put()

class Company(ndb.Model):
  administrator         = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, repeated=True)
  manager               = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, repeated=True)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def jwrite(self, **kw):
    return self.response.out.write( json.dumps(kw) )

class require(BaseHandler):
  @staticmethod
  def login(handler):
    def check_requirements(self, *a, **kw):
      if not self.auth.get_user_by_session():
        self.redirect('/', abort=True)
      else:
        return handler(self, *a, **kw)
    return check_requirements

class role(BaseHandler):
  @staticmethod
  def administrator(handler):
    def check_requirements(self, *a, **kw):
      # I didn't care much about optimizing queries
      # since this isn't frequent operation.
      # For more frequent calls, I'd consider projections.
      companies = ndb.get_multi( *a )
      # Next lines checks if current user is administrator 
      # for all companies passed to the function
      if not self.user.key in reduce(lambda x, y: x if x != y else y, map(lambda c: c.administrator, companies)):
        return self.jwrite( error = 'Permission denied. Administrator required.' )
      else:
        return handler(self, *a, **kw)
    return check_requirements

  @staticmethod
  def manager(handler):
    def check_requirements(self, *a, **kw):
      companies = ndb.get_multi( *a )
      # Next lines checks if current user is manager
      # or administrator (since admin has higher privileges) 
      # for all companies passed to the function
      if not self.user.key in reduce(lambda x, y: x if x != y else y, map(lambda c: c.manager + c.administrator, companies)):
        return self.jwrite( error = 'Permission denied. Manager or Administrator required.' )
      else:
        return handler(self, *a, **kw)
    return check_requirements

class ApiHandler(BaseHandler):
  @require.login
  def post(self, model, action, key=''):
    method = '_post_%s' % model
    try:
      getattr(self, method)(action, key)
    except Exception as error:
      return self.jwrite( error = error)

  def _post_company(self, action, key):

    if action == 'create':
      data = dict(self.request.POST)
      """ Company.create( data ) method:
          Populates Company instance with POST data.
          Assigns first user that created the company
            both administrator and manager roles.
      """
      key_ = Company.create( data ) 
      if key_:
        self.user.company = key_
      return

    elif action == 'delete':

      @role.administrator
      def delete_all_user_companies(self, *a):
        ndb.delete_multi( *a )
        self.user.company = None
        return

      delete_all_user_companies( self, self.user.company )

    elif action == 'update':

      @role.manager
      def update_company(self, *a ):
        data = dict(self.request.POST)
        """ Company.update( key, data ) method:
            Populates Company instance with POST data
        """
        key_ = Company.update( key, data )
        if key_:
          return

      update_company(self, ndb.Key(Company, key))
```

and to answer my own questions:

1. I had issues with naming inside Company class - there were property administrator and decorator with the same name. So I moved decorators to the API, into the new class (role) for convenience. When I wrote decorators I realized I can use them for any other models (with manager and administrator fields), so I guess this was a good call (;
2. Writing decorators took some time and experimenting with mapping and reducing arrays but I've managed to pull it of. I'm not sure about passing arguments to the decorator tho'. Maybe I should do queries outside decorators? Or pass matched items to the handler function? I'll have to look into it...
3. *...and delete ones where he is while keeping ones where he isn't administrator* This is why I did queries inside decorator in the first place. But still not sure if it's smart (;
4. I could still use answer to this one.

Hope this helps someone...